# Spring boot 1.4.2 with Tomcat 8.5.8 crashes, port already in use. Works fine with Tomcat 8.5.6

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've got two relatively simple Spring Boot apps.  They both use Tomcat 8.5.6 with Spring Boot 1.4.2.  And they work fine.

For grins and giggles, I changed the Tomcat version to the latest version in that tree, 8.5.8.

Now, neither app starts.  "Port 8080 already in use".  Somehow, Spring Boot seems to start port 8080 twice (or is not catching the fact that it has already started and tries again).

Any ideas?

Comment: and before anyone asks snarkily, I use netstat to ensure that nothing is using 8080 before the "mvn spring-boot:run"...

Comment: Press Win+R enter "cmd" press enter, type in "netstat -ano" look for a process which uses the port 8080 when you localized it look at the right column ans look up what pID (process ID) this task has and after enter "taskkill /PID <pID>"

Comment: `For grins and giggles, I changed the Tomcat version to the latest version in that tree, 8.5.8.` how and why? why can't you just use the tomcat comes with spring boot starter web.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the Tomcat team refactoring the embedded startup in a way that broke Spring Boot.

It's fixed in Tomcat 8.5.9